# Clear cache when time is up in django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have problem with issue, with cache. I want to clear cache always when time is up.
Below is part of my model in django 1.8 but app didn't used my method `clear_cache_when_times_up`.

Is class model good place to clear cache when time is up?
I want to  clear cache on list and on detail page, because there I use time.

```
class Article(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    short_text = models.TextField(max_length=10000, default='')
    livestream_url = models.URLField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    livestream_from = models.DateTimeField('livestream from', blank=True, null=True)
    livestream_to = models.DateTimeField('livestream to', blank=True, null=True)

    def has_livestream(self):
        if self.livestream_from is None and self.livestream_to is None:
            return False
        return (self.livestream_from <= timezone.now()) and (self.livestream_to >= timezone.now())

    def clear_cache_when_times_up(self):
        if self.has_livestream():
            print('################## test #################')
            return cache.clear()
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? That's not usually how caches work; rather, when you try to get an item from the cache, you check it has not expired.

Comment: @DanielRoseman becase I'm counting down time on page and time is up clock still counting time from start (solution with click is in js).

Comment: why do you cache such trivial things at all??